# Difference between sensors and receptors?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am wondering what the difference is between a **sensor** and a **receptor**, and whether or not there is a similar pairing between the word **actuator** and another word.

For instance:

> Receptor is to Sensor as ??? is to Actuator

**Motor?**

Comment: There is the word `Effector`, but I'm also struggling how to pair that all up.

Answer (score 1):

Form the **M-W**:

[*Sensor*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sensor) means

> a device that detects or senses heat, light, sound, motion, etc., and then reacts to it in a particular way

and [*Receptor*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/receptor) means

> biology : a nerve ending that senses changes in light, temperature, pressure, etc., and causes the body to react in a particular way

In fact, these are two different things that could be combined.

> In a sensory system, **a sensory receptor** is a sensory nerve ending that responds to a stimulus in the internal or external environment of an organism. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensory_receptor))

Comment: Thanks @Eilia (+1) - makes sense. Is there a complementary word for actuator, like motor, as I suggest?

Comment: You're welcome. Perhaps **biological  actuator/ effector** .

Answer (score 0):

**Sensors**:

> These are the systems or an organised assembly or molecule which can
>   detect any optical(light, color) and/or chemical (ion or molecule)
>   and/or thermal(heat) changes in their surrounding and/or within by
>   providing (Signaling) optical and/or chemical and and/or thermal
>   changes.

**Receptors:**

> These are the systems or an organised assembly or molecule which can
>   receive optical (light) and/or chemicals (ion or molecule) and/or heat
>   changes in their surrounding and/or within, by or not by providing
>   (Signaling) any optical and/or chemical and and/or thermal changes.

i.e., all sensors are receptors but all receptors are not sensors.

Comment: Do you have any references to back up your definitions? On ELU we prefer quotes with weblinks where possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say **muscle**.

I think that the "translation" is biological vs artificial: sensor and receptor are functionally equivalent, but receptors are grown in the body while sensors are built components of a machine.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sensor

> sen·sor  (sĕn′sər, -sôr′)
>   n.
>   1. A device, such as a photoelectric cell, that receives and responds to a signal or stimulus.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/receptor

> re·cep·tor  (rĭ-sĕp′tər)
>   n.
>   1. Physiology A specialized cell or group of nerve endings that responds to sensory stimuli.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actuator):

> "An actuator is a component of machines that is responsible for moving or controlling a mechanism or system.  An actuator requires a control signal and source of energy..."

So, we want the **biological equivalent** of something that causes a movement, using energy, when it gets a control signal.  That sounds like a **muscle** to me.